# Calling a mixin with a return value twice in the same scope

Tags: less

I'm building a LESS file containing a list of color variables that are used through our project. Most of these colors are simple colors (red, blue...), but I want a few of them to be automatically "computed" from the other colors. For example, I have made a mixin to automatically create a color that "stands out" from another color. Following the LESS documentation, I "simulate" a return value by defining a new variable in the mixin, so that I can use it next.

```
.stand-out-color(@baseColor, @rate) when (lightness(@baseColor) >= 50%) {
  @standOutColor: darken(@baseColor, @rate);
}
.stand-out-color(@baseColor, @rate) when (lightness(@baseColor) < 50%) {
  @standOutColor: lighten(@baseColor, @rate);
}

.stand-out-color(red, 10%);
@my-first-color: @standOutColor; // A slightly different red, perfect

.stand-out-color(blue, 10%);
@my-second-color: @standOutColor; // The same slightly different red, not the blue I expected
```

Unfortunately, the return value is written after the first call, and never changed afterwards.
After reading the documentation again, I got this part: "There is only one exception, variable is not copied if the caller contains a variable with the same name (that includes variables defined by another mixin call)."

So it works as it should, but I don't have any idea how to achieve what I want, which is a function I can call more than once within the same scope. As I'm defining a list of global variables, I don't think I can play with scopes to avoid this behavior. **Is there any other way to achieve this?**

Comment: First of all discover [`contrast`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) function (i.e. you don't really need a mixin like this). Aside of that, usually you can isolate each "call" with `& {...}`, but yes, if you're about using such mixin for defining global vars it won't work. So the [`functions` plugin](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins) comes to rescue.

Comment: At first read I didn't understand the `contrast`  function, but indeed it does exactly what I need. It is a bit more verbose that what I aimed for initially (I have to repeat the "logic") but it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "logic" (assuming the the adjustment value e.g.`10%` or `darken/lighten(@original-color, ...)` colors themselves can always be moved to a separate variable(s) to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, thanks to *seven-phases-max*'s comment to my question. It solves my initial problem, which is that I needed to compute slightly darker/lighter color variables depending on another variable.

The [`contrast`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) function of LESS solves my issue, by letting me specify which color to take depending if a color is "dark" or "light".

Applied to my example:

```
@my-first-color: contrast(@original-color, darken(@original-color, 10%), lighten(@original-color, 10%));
```